# How to make Adobe AIR application for iOS supporting both new and old screen size

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I've been a Flash animator for a few years and recently tried my hand at developing a simple iOS application using Flash CS6 and AS3.

When I began development I was creating for the iPhone 4S' screen size, however now with the release of the iPhone 5 the new screen size obviously doesn't fill the screen, resulting in the black-bar letterboxing at the top and bottom of the screen.

I have three questions to ask:

1. Is it possible to release two different versions of the app onto the App Store for separate devices or does it have to be universal? (I believe the answer is the latter but I can't find a definitive answer)
2. Is it possible to have a stage size that matches the iPhone 5's larger display but cut off the bottom (for example) for the previous iPhone sizes, in effect just adding some information to the bottom of the screen exclusively for iPhone 5 users?
3. If (2) is not possible, is there coding examples available change positions of items on the screen? For example, I have a title and taskbar as well as a background, could I code it to stretch to the size of the device screen rather than the stage? And would I need to alter the stage size or is there code available to do that for me?

I'm quite new to the programming aspect of AS3 and I'm sorry if there are answers that you feel that I should know, but I'm really thankful for your time to read and answer and I thank you in advance for your replies!

Ben Kahan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While all of your options are possible, you'll want to make sure your program dynamically lays itself out and resizes visual assets depending on screen size, pixel density and orientation.

More here:

[One Application, Five Screens (Including the iPad)](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/04/one_application_five_screens.html)

and

[Writing Multiscreen AIR Apps](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/writing_multiscreen_air_apps.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into doing number 3! 1 will be a hell to maintain, 2 will piss off users with smaller screen. If you design your application a bit more flexible, that would also mean you have an app that works on android ;)

I don't have any particular code for handling different screen sizes, but I remember reading about it back when Adobe introduced FP for mobile. This [article](http://www.kongregate.com/pages/multiscreen-best-practices) gives a lot of good advice for delveloping for mobile (even though it is a bit old) -- maybe you can find something that is more up to date though google :)

Comment: Thanks for the link but it seems like it's only useful for browsers - [I found an article here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/multiple-screen-sizes.html) but it's still difficult to see what's applicable to purely stretching the stage to the screen size.
I'll play around with it and see what effect it has, hanks for your reply!